# ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC - Log Each Request to Database

Tags: entity-framework, logging, asp.net-core-mvc, configure, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to database log the time it takes my app to process each request, and some other info such as IP addresses for each request received.

I have added an app.Use step in Startup.cs -> Configure with dependency injection to my dbcontext.  I receive no errors when the below code fires and my MVC pipeline seems to fire correctly.

The issue is that any calls that involves dbcontext seems to exit the code.  In the below example, `db.PageRequests.Add(pageRequest);` causes the code to exit.  The page is still rendered fine but is of course missing anything appended to the response.

I can't help but think it's an async/threading issue but I am lost for ideas.  I also tried making the dbcontext interaction both sync and async but it doesn't help.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            await next.Invoke();
            sw.Stop();

            PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest()
            {
                ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                loadTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
            };
            db.PageRequests.Add(pageRequest);  // this code exits and page is rendered.  Code below here is never fired.
            db.SaveChanges();

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "<p>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>" + context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress + "<p>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString + "<p>");

        });
    // other app.use statements here
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a comment in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that pointed me in the right direction.

> Because middleware is constructed at app startup, not per-request, scoped lifetime services used by middleware constructors aren't shared with other dependency-injected types during each request. If you must share a scoped service between your middleware and other types, add these services to the Invoke method's signature.

I believe the dbcontext injected into the Configure method is no longer available after app startup and therefore no accessible during each request.  **It's frustrating that this didn't raise an error.**

**The solution was to move the middleware delegate to a class and inject the context in the invoke method.**

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
public class Logging
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public Logging(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        await _next(context);
        sw.Stop();

        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest()
        {
            ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
            loadTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
        };
        await db.PageRequests.AddAsync(pageRequest); 
        db.SaveChanges();

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "<p>");
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>" + context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress + "<p>");
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString + "<p>");
    }

}

public static class LoggingMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLogging(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<Logging>();
    }
}`
```

You can then add the Use statement to Startup.cs -> Configure

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {

        app.UseLogging();

    }
```